# Setting focus to an iframe using selenium by its frame index which does not have neither Name nor Id

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, selenium-webdriver, browser-automation, c#

I am using selenium with C# to focus on an iframe which does not contain any name or id. I have tried to use an index 0 as there is only one frame on the page but I am getting the following errors:

```
OpenQA.Selenium.InvalidSelectorException 
 & Error: The given selector frame#0,iframe#0 is either invalid or does not result in a WebElement. The following error occurred:
InvalidSelectorError: An invalid or illegal selector was specified 
 & InnerException
```

Any idea how I can focus on the iframe apart from these 3 options?
Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: What have to tried? Can we see your script?

Comment: I am using WebDriver.SwitchTo().Frame();

Comment: Code + URL to test please.

Answer (score 1):

If there is one `iframe` , it might be the window you are working on. However, you can find no. of iframes using List

```
List<WebElement> iframe_element=driver.finelements(By.tagName("iframe");
System.out.println("number of iframes"+iframe_elemen.size());
```

Then you should try hit and trial method to find out the `iframe` to work on using loop and you can switch to iframe using 3 ways.

```
switchTo.frame(int frame_number);
switchTo.frame(String frame_name);
switchTo.frame(WebElement frame_element);
```

This code in java though, but crux will remain the same as i only know to work on selenium with java.

Answer (score 0):

To access the elements in  iframe, you need to switch to that frame:

```
driver.switchTo().frame(id or name of the frame) 
driver.switchTo().frame(index of the frame) (Ist frame have index 0)
driver.switchTo().frame(0);
```

To move back to the normal content:

```
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```